# Insert and extract a XML from a PDF with JAVA substring

Tags: xml, pdf, insert, extract

I'm changing an application that extracts an XML from an HTML file with the Java substring method.

I'm thinking to migrate the HTML files to PDF files but I have to maintain compatibility.

Is there any library (fop, itext, ...) that allows me to insert an XML into a PDF without showing it when it is opened and that I can continue extracting the XML as before, using Java substring ?

Comment: PDF is a binary format. Thus, it is not recommended to handle it as if it were text (and trying to take a `substring` from it means you handle it as a string, i.e. as text). Aside from that, the PDF standard allows the inclusion of private data, even as a stream, and that technique can easily be employed for embedding your XML, even in a way that makes it recognizable for PDF-unaware programs. Any general purpose PDF library should, therefore, allow you to embed the XML, iText does and others surely do, too.

Comment: Thanks!

The reason why I need to continue extracting the XML with substring is to maintain backwards compatibility to multiple users who are doing that to extract the XML.

Comment: It is difficult to tell without you showing how exactly your code with that `substring` call looks like.